# Does Nim language has shorter notation for object initialization?

Tags: nim-lang

The example [from docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut2.html)

```
type
  BinaryTree*[T] = ref object # BinaryTree is a generic type with
                              # generic param ``T``
    le, ri: BinaryTree[T]     # left and right subtrees; may be nil
    data: T                   # the data stored in a node

proc newNode*[T](data: T): BinaryTree[T] =
  # constructor for a node
  new(result)
  result.data = data
```

Is it possible to use something like one-line shortcut like

```
proc newNode*[T](data: T): BinaryTree[T] = 
  data.new(data = data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The tutorial](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#procedures-result-variable) says: "Note that referential data types will be nil at the start of the procedure, and thus may require manual initialisation" and [here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#advanced-types-reference-and-pointer-types) "To allocate a new traced object, the built-in procedure new **must** be used". But if you really need to save that line, you can make a template:

```
template aNewNode(data: untyped): void =
  new(result)
  result.data = data

proc newNode*[T](data: T): BinaryTree[T] =
  # constructor for a node
  aNewNode data
```